# Double screen app,access method in first window from second window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have an app that works in two monitor, in window 1 (mainWindow) there is a frame and content will change during app life, in second window  the content are always the same. This the mainWindow:

```
 void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


         //main window content will load in a frame.
        if (Generics.loadingStatus == 0)
        {
            _mainFrame.Source = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            Generics.loadingStatus = 1;
        }

         SecondScreen win2 = new SecondScreen ();
        var secondaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Where(s => !s.Primary).FirstOrDefault();

        if (secondaryScreen != null)
        {
            if (!this.IsLoaded)
                win2.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

            var workingArea = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea;

            win2.Left = workingArea.Left;
            win2.Top = workingArea.Top;
            win2.Width = workingArea.Width;
            win2.Height = workingArea.Height;

            // If window isn't loaded then maxmizing will result in the window displaying on the primary monitor
            if (win2.IsLoaded)
                win2.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

        }
        win2.Show();

    }
```

This in the second window:

```
 private void Window_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Application curApp = Application.Current;
        var mainWnd = curApp.MainWindow as MainWindow;

        //ActualClass is a string variable that i set every time i change the content of the main frame in mainwindow
        if (mainWnd.ActualClass== "Page2.xaml")
        {
           //here i have to call a method of the Page2 class to launch an operation in Page2.cs only if the current page displayed in mainwindow frame is Page2.xaml

        }


    }
```

From the second window i need to call a public method of the Page2.cs class, i can check correctly if Page2.cs is actually visualized in mainwindow (by setting a string varible) but i can't find the current instance of the class to invoke the method...How i can do?

Comment: You want to access from Window2 to Window1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way;

```
private void Window_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    Application curApp = Application.Current;
    var mainWnd = curApp.MainWindow as MainWindow;

    //ActualClass is a string variable that i set every time i change the content of the main frame in mainwindow
    if (mainWnd.ActualClass== "Page2.xaml")
    {
       //here i have to call a method of the Page2 class to launch an operation in Page2.cs only if the current page displayed in mainwindow frame is Page2.xaml
           var content = mainWnd._mainFrame.Content as Page2Class;
            if (content != null)
            {
                content.Method();
            }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried accessing data context, something like

```
var myClass = mainWnd.DataContext as Page2Class;
myClass.MyMethod();
```

Comment: ok in this way i can find the method in window 1 from window 2,but the myClass created it is null and next in myClass.MyMethod() the app crash... I run this method only when Page2Class is running in window 1 ...